# iterating and displaying values in R

Tags: javascript, r

https://gyazo.com/1f2cba6dbb7047bc08e820f7c673fb0d

In JavaScript i think the code would look like this:

```
r=4
q=0.02
V=0.01;
S=0.1;
U=0.89;
for(i<200){
     i++;
     v = V;
     s = S;
     u = U;
     V = r*v*s;
     S = s - r*v*s + q*u;
     U = 1 - v - s;
 }`
```

Can anyone help me translate this code into R and to show the values at each iteration?

Thank you kindly

Comment: Would you like to save the values to a data frame or list after each iteration, or simply print them to the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it in R

```
n = 200
r = 4
q = 0.02
V = double(n)
S = double(n)
U = double(n)
V[1] = 0.01
S[1] = 0.1
U[1] = 0.89
for (i in 2:n){
    V[i] = r * V[i-1] * S[i-1]
    S[i] = S[i-1] - r * V[i-1] * S[i-1] + q * U[i-1]
    U[i] = 1 - V[i] - S[i]
    }
final = cbind(V, S, U)
```

Each iteration is saved in rows of `final`. Note, the `U[i]` here is different than what you provided, but agrees with the formula you gave in that screenshot.